# Why is this question locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433528/check-if-f2r%e2%86%921-%e2%88%9e-where-fx-x21-is-injective-function-or-not) has only two downvotes, which is not enough to keep it off the front page.  I'd therefore like to downvote it, but can't, because it is locked for mysterious reasons.

Because this does not seem to fit of any sort of new pattern, my best guess is that the question is locked because a moderator clicked something by mistake.  But I'm curious whether there's a deeper explanation.

Comment: For easier access, I will add links to [the timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/433528/timeline) and [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/433528/revisions) of the post.

Comment: The link Steven gives now takes us to a post on m.se, closed as a duplicate and deleted by a moderator there.

Comment: As [pointed out in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2022/10/30), this might have been caused by a bug concerning migrations. A related post: [All question migrations are currently broken across the entire SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383353) (on [meta.se]).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what happened there, I merely voted to close it, and it got locked without me doing anything. Perhaps that was an automatic response to the score being negative? Other things I've voted to close since becoming a mod haven't gotten a lock like that.

In any case, I removed the lock—it is still closed—vote away!

Comment: Quickly looking [through the corresponding FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228), one thing that is described there is this: "You may sometimes see a lock from the Community user with no corresponding migration or deletion event: in that case, it was a migration, but a moderator later cleared the question's migration history." But your description suggests that it was something else.

Comment: Aha, I selected the migrate option when voting to close, perhaps that also had something to do with it.

Comment: When looking at the [list of migrated questions on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated), I do not see this one. I do not have sufficient reputation to [view the same list on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/tools?tab=migrated) - perhaps somebody could check whether the question isn't displayed there among rejected migrations. (Although I will admit that it doesn't seem very likely.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak it's not on any of the migration lists (particularly Rejected or Away), only under the closed questions tab.

Comment: Actually, now: 1) The [revision history on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/433528/revisions) says "migrated away". 2) On MSE there [is a migration target](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4565137/revisions) (now deleted). 3) I see the question [among the migrations on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools). (I am pretty sure that when I posted the previous comments, I saw none of these three things. But maybe I remember it wrong...?)

Comment: @MartinSleziak it wasn't there before, no. I can now see it on the outbound list here on MO, and it wasn't there before. In this instance, it was probably not in good enough shape to migrate, I was being too generous to the OP. But we live and learn